# Export multiple image versions in GIMP (different resolution)

Tags: gimp

I want to export my image with multiple sizes (192x192, 144x144, 96x96, 72x72, 44x44).

Is there an easy and effective way to do that or do I have to scale it manually each time?

Answer (score 0):

See the [`ofn-export-sizes` script](https://sourceforge.net/projects/gimp-tools/files/scripts/). The ZIP contains an HTML doc. Installation instructions at the bottom of the download page.